# How can i use uClibc for C library ? busybox for system init ? and Thumb-2 instructions for my Yocto Linux image

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto

I m using SAMA5D27 SOM1 EK1 board and yocto project. I build for it a linux kernel image and a rootfs to make it boot following the steps described here:
https://www.at91.com/linux4sam/bin/view/Linux4SAM/Sama5d27Som1EKMainPage

The size of the rootfs and the image together is 15 Mega octet which is out of my needs while i m trying to use 8 Mega octet QSPI flash memory.

Now I am trying to build the smallest possible Linux image. While i was searching on net , i found some solutions like using busybox instead of systemV or systemd , using uClibc instead of glibc, Thumb-2 instructions instead of 32 Arm instructions.. Do you have any idea where can I check this options ? And how can I make these changes ? Do you have any other solutions to make smaller image size ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use uClibc as the C library:

```
TCLIBC = "uclibc"
```

To replace init and login managers with the ones from busybox (you can find example in `poky-tiny.conf`):

```
VIRTUAL-RUNTIME_login_manager = "busybox"
VIRTUAL-RUNTIME_init_manager = "busybox"
```

To use Thumb instructions:

```
ARM_INSTRUCTION_SET = "thumb"
```

Comment: Besides, do you have an idea about in which file i can find my current default Lib C and init system used ?

Comment: If you did not change anything, it'll be default values defined in `meta/conf/distro/defaultsetup.conf` or one of the included files. You can probably check those variables in devconsole, but I don't have an answer with me right now.

Comment: Thank you very much, that was useful

Comment: Hello buddy, please do you have an idea how can I use musl C library instead of uclibc ? In fact uclibc is removed from latest releases of yocto project and I m using SUMO release

Comment: same principle here: `TCLIBC = "musl"`

Comment: I tried this and it does not work, besides, i added meta-musl layer in bblayers.conf then re build and same result

Comment: do you get the same compilation error (systemd fails)?

Comment: Clean up your post, show which meta layers you're using (do not use meta-musl) and post the exact error.